# How to remove jQuery event listener from parent without removing similar listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering if there is an elegant way to remove specific event listeners from a HTML element without affecting similar events.

Ex.

```
var a = {
  addEvent: function(){
     $('body').on('click', function(){
      //does something here.
     });
  }
}

var b = {
  addEvent: function(){
     $('body').on('click', function(){
      //does something else here.
     });
   }
}

a.addEvent();
b.addEvent();
```

**So the question is:** how do I remove object `a`'s on click event without removing   `b`'s event?

```
$('body').off('click'); //removes both event listeners
```

I assume most ways will kill both listeners. It would be great to see any elegant responses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option would be to [namespace the events](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/):

```
var a = {
  addEvent: function(){
     $('body').on('click.a', function(){
       //does something here.
     });
  }
}

var b = {
  addEvent: function(){
     $('body').on('click.b', function(){
       //does something here.
     });
   }
}

a.addEvent();
b.addEvent();

$('body').off('click.a'); //removes the a event listener
```

Answer (score 2):

Great answer Josh (and I will give you the points).

The below does not work (I made a bad assumption to believe this would work)... striking through so no one uses this answer. Thanks @Guffa.

<s>I found another solution to this issue worth sharing:</s>

```
var x = $('body').on('click', function(){
                //does something here
        });

var y = $('body').on('click', function(){
                //does something else here
        });

x.off('click'); //this does not remove the event handler assigned to y
```

(I did not write the code inside the original objects for clarity)

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work, it will remove both event handlers. The jQuery objects in `x` and `y` doesn't keep any information of what they were used for, so they can't be used to undo that.